# Showing specific content from a combination of two drop-down lists

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I am trying to display content (text, images, video) based on selections from two drop-down lists. It is proving to be quite tricky as my second drop-down list updates depending on the first one. Here is my HTML code so far:

```
<div class="margins1">
<h2>Main Body Part</h2>
<select size="1" id="BodyPart" title="" name="BodyPart">
<option value="">-Select Body Part-</option>
<option value="chest">Chest</option>
<option value="biceps">Biceps</option>
</select>

<div class="container">
<div class="chest">
<select>
<option value ="chestpress">Chest Press</option>
<option value ="inclinechestpress">Incline Chest Press</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="chest chestpress">
CHEST PRESS
</div>
<div class="chest inclinechestpress">
INCLINE CHEST PRESS    
</div>

<div class="biceps">
<select>
<option value="bicepcurls">Bicep Curls</option>
<option value="hammercurls">Hammer Curls</option>
</select>

<div class="bicepcurls">
BICEP CURLS
</div>
<div class="hammercurls">
HAMMER CURLS   
</div>     
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my JavaScript above the HTML:

```
   <script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#BodyPart').bind('change', function() {
        var elements = $('div.container').children().hide(); // hide all the elements
        var value = $(this).val();

        if (value.length) { // if somethings' selected
            elements.filter('.' + value).show(); // show the ones we want
        }
    }).trigger('change');
        });
        </script>
```

So as you can see, if the user clicks 'Chest', they're presented with another drop-down menu containing two chest exercises. The same logic is used for 'Biceps'. However, I've tried to show a piece of text (the exercise name) if the user clicks a specific exercise of the body part category. The problem is, both pieces of text show no matter what exercise the user has selected.

For example, if the user selects the body part 'Biceps', both 'BICEP CURLS' and 'HAMMER CURLS' texts will display no matter what exercise is chosen in the second drop-down menu. Would anyone be able to provide some help or guidance as to how I can make this work?

Many thanks for your time and support.

Comment: Add seperate script for selecting exercise similar to the one you have written

Comment: @Tyranicangel I have done, it's in the HTML above?

Comment: You have written script for selecting a body part.After that you have to attach similar scripts to the other two select elements which show the list of exercises

Comment: @Tyranicangel I'm not having much luck with this. Would you mind showing me what you mean? Apologies for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML:

```
<div class="margins1">
<h2>Main Body Part</h2>
<select size="1" id="BodyPart" title="" name="BodyPart">
<option value="">-Select Body Part-</option>
<option value="chest">Chest</option>
<option value="biceps">Biceps</option>
</select>

<div class="container">
<div class="chest">
<select class="excercise_select">
<option value ="__select__">SELECT</option>
<option value ="chestpress">Chest Press</option>
<option value ="inclinechestpress">Incline Chest Press</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="chest">
<div class="chestpress exercise_name">
CHEST PRESS
</div>
<div class="inclinechestpress exercise_name">
INCLINE CHEST PRESS    
</div>
</div>

<div class="biceps">
<select class="excercise_select">
<option value ="__select__">SELECT</option>
<option value="bicepcurls">Bicep Curls</option>
<option value="hammercurls">Hammer Curls</option>
</select>
<div class="biceps">
<div class="bicepcurls exercise_name">
BICEP CURLS
</div>
<div class="hammercurls exercise_name">
HAMMER CURLS   
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Your js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var elements = $('div.container').children().hide();
        $('#BodyPart').change(function() {
            elements.hide();
            var value = $(this).val();
            if (value.length) { // if somethings' selected
                elements.filter('.' + value).show(); // show the ones we want
            }
        });

        $('.excercise_select').change(function(){
            console.log(123);
            $('.exercise_name').hide();
            var subele=$('.exercise_name');
            subele.filter('.'+$(this).val()).show();
        });
   });
```

Comment: Will give this a try and let you know, thanks so much!

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. It generates the same result as my script (2 exercise names display when only 1 should).

Comment: I misspelt the classname in my script

Comment: Nearly there! But for some reason it doesn't work with chest, only biceps? I've had a good look through and cannot identify why...

Comment: Check your html code for errors with class and ids its working pretty fine for me

Comment: Okay sorry, got it working now. But both exercises appear until I click a specific exercise.

Comment: Add a dummmy select option like <option value='__select__'>--SELECT--</option> for both exercise_select

Comment: I've done that:

`<div class="container">
<div class="chest">
<select class="exercise_select">
<option value="select">-Select Exercise-</option>
<option value ="chestpress">Chest Press</option>
<option value ="inclinechestpress">Incline Chest Press</option>
</select>
</div>`

Still no luck.

Comment: This is cause your elements has the exercise names into it Remove the class chest and biceps from the divs  <div class="bicepcurls exercise_name">

Comment: But that's just written text? And even after removing 'Exercise' from 'Select Exercise', it still doesn't work. However, if I click 'Biceps' AFTER selecting an exercise from 'Chest', only then nothing shows up. If you know what I mean?

Comment: any idea? Do you see what I mean when both exercises show up until you click a specific exercise. Almost there!! Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Nope, still not working. Are those spelling mistakes on purpose? There is exercise and excercise. Even when correcting it doesn't work. Does it work for you?

Comment: Nope the spellings are just typo and it works absolutely fine for me

Comment: Aren't both exercises still displaying when you click a body part? For me, they only single out when I click the specific exercise. Would you be able to jsfiddle it please? Many thanks

Comment: I'm going to tick the above as a correct solution, although it doesn't fully do what I want. However, it has helped me a lot, so thanks so much for your time.